# Como fazer o upload de imagem usando Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, imagem, spring-boot

Estou aprendendo a usar o `Spring Boot` e preciso criar um campo no formulário que carregue a imagem a ser utilizada. Como faço para mapear o diretório e salvar em uma determinada pasta do projeto?

**Exemplo:** através do formulário, o usuário irá carregar a foto. Ao invés de salvar a imagem no banco de dados, como faço para salvar apenas o diretório que irá carregar a imagem na `view`? Acrescentando, e se possível, como carregar essa imagem pela classe de controle?

Por favor, *Antes de saírem negativando minha pergunta*, vi algumas respostas, até aqui no `stackoverflow`, mas ainda estou com dúvidas de como proceder dentro das classes de domínio. Exemplo de classe de domínio:

**Observação:** estou utilizando `MySQL`.

```
package com.ptestes.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class HotSite implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String pageTitle;

    @?????
    private <?????> img;

    /*Getters and Setters*/
}
```

Desde já, muito obrigada! ^_^

Comment: Acredito que [isso](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-data/springjpa-save-filesimages-mysql-database-lob-annotation) pode te ajudar.

Comment: O artigo é legal, mas ele ensina a salvar direto no BD. Gostaria de salvar o diretório e carregar a imagem usando o `controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recebi a resposta através da mesma pergunta em um outro fórum. Caso esteja com a mesma dúvida e queira ler a discussão completa, [leia aqui](http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-como-fazer-o-upload-de-imagem-usando-spring-boot/376998).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não seja o ideal gravar o bitmap de uma imagem no banco de dados. Abaixo está um trecho de código onde eu faço o upload de uma imagem para o servidor da Amazon (S3), no nome do arquivo eu uso um prefixo pré definido e o ID do objeto, dessa forma quando eu quero buscar a imagem eu faço uma requisição para o servidor buscando esse prefixo + ID. Espero que isso te ajude a ter uma ideia.

```
public URI uploadProfilePicture(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    UserSS user = UserService.authenticated();
    if (user == null)
        throw new AuthorizationException("Acesso negado!");

    BufferedImage jpgImage = imageService.getJpgImageFromFile(multipartFile);
    jpgImage = imageService.cropSquare(jpgImage);
    jpgImage = imageService.resize(jpgImage, size);

    String fileName = prefix + user.getId() + ".jpg";

    return s3Service.uploadFile(imageService.getInputStream(jpgImage, "jpg"), fileName, "image");
}
```

Comment: Obrigada! Vou testar! 

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Lob   //representa um campo do tipo blob no bd
    private byte[] img;  //armazena arquivo como um byte array
```

Comment: Olá, Lucas! Muito obrigada por responder! Talvez eu tenha expressado mal minha pergunta, vou corrigir. Mas lendo por aí, e posso estar errada, o que é provável, vi algumas pessoas dizendo que carregar imagem direto no banco de dados pode deixá-lo pesado. Então, eu queria saber como mapear a URL ou  diretório de uma pasta dentro do projeto?

Comment: eu quem li errado mesmo rs, na verdade fiquei curioso também, sinceramente sempre salvei no bd meus arquivos, mas acredito que para salvar o caminho também não tenha segredo,na minha humilde opinião o campo seria uma string, você poderia salvar o caminho no diretório da sua escolha usando Files.Move() e salvando o diretório, e para recupera o arquivo você poderia simplesmente ler com buffered image, ex: BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(img);

Comment: Vou tentar! ^_^ Obrigada!